# Passing method argument through ternary operator in java

Tags: java, return-value, ternary-operator, ocpjp

**Code:**

```
public class Foo {

    static void test(String s){
        System.out.println("String called");
    }

    static void test(int s){
        System.out.println("int called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        test(5>8? 5:8);         // Line 1
        test(5>8? "he":"ha");   // Line 2

        test(5>8? 5:"ha");      // Line 3

        System.out.println(5<8? 5:"ha"); //Line 4
    }
}
```

When I execute this code I get the following Error at `Line 3`

```
Foo.java:24: error: no suitable method found for test(INT#1)
                test(5>8? 5:"ha");              // Line 3
                ^
```

Using similar type in the ternary operator does not give error. But using different types gives error only to the method call `test(5>8? 5:"ha");` but it works for the call `System.out.println(5<8? 5:"ha");`

When I add another overloaded method `static void test(Object s){}`, then the `//Line 3` compiles.

Can anyone please explain me this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every expression in Java has a type.  There are some complicated rules in the Java Language Specification, in the section on [the conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) that tell us how to find the type of a conditional expression such as `5 > 8 ? 5 : "ha"`.  But in simple terms, you always get the most specific type that both the second and third arguments are members of.

- For `5 > 8 ? 5 : 8`, both `5` and `8` are `int`, so this whole expression has type `int`.
- For `5 > 8 ? "he" : "ha"`, both `"he"` and `"ha"` are `String`, so this whole expression has type `String`.
- For `5 > 8 ? 5 : "ha"`, the most specific type that fits both `5` and `"ha"` is `Object`.  So this whole expression has type `Object`.

Now since you have versions of `test` that accept `int` and accept `String`, the expressions `test ( 5 > 8 ? 5 : 8 )` and `test ( 5 > 8 ? "he" : "ha" )` both compile.

But if you don't have a version of `test` that accepts `Object`, then `test ( 5 > 8 ? 5 : "ha" )` can't compile.

This is an over-simplification.  The rules are significantly more complicated than I've described, but this is mostly because they consider the various cases involving `null` operands, auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.

Comment: Now I understand how to determine the return type of a ternary operator. Based on your explanation I wondered whether the method `System.out.println()` has an overloaded method which takes Object as parameter and found there is an `public void println(Object x)` method in PrintStream. If you could add this point in your answer it will be useful for others.

Comment: I feel that's kind of a different issue.  Also, most Java programmers are aware that they can pass any object they like into `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method before the expression is evaluated. Since the method doesn't have an overload for *test(Object o)*, it doesn't work.

Call the method after resolving the left side expression.

```
5>8?test(5):test("ha")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the function

`test(5>8? 5:8);`

Method (in present case) is meant to send the parameter hence whole thing inside the parentheses is considered as parameter and there is no appropriate/suitable method to handle such kind of call (whose parameter should be Object) as you are evaluating int and String in one of the statements . Hence the Ternary operator cannot be implemented there.

Hence you can use code like this

```
(5 > 8) ? test(param1): test(param2);
```

or create another test method which accepts Object as parameter and then evaluate things inside that test method. like this

```
void test(Object o){
    //manipulate things here
}
```